# Cannot use arraylist and yet system.collections is defined

Tags: c#

[image]

What title says, and i have tried `System.Collections.ArrayList A1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList();`

Comment: Never use `ArrayList`

Comment: You have `ArrayList` in your namespace, I think it is the source of error. Also agreed with @T.S.

Comment: Specifically `ArrayList` is a very old class left over from .Net 1.0 when there were no generics.  You should always prefer to use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: ... and for problem at hand: Never use class or namespace names of the framework itself: `NetFramework,S6.D1.ArrayList`.

Comment: But if you still want to use it try adding `using ArrList = System.Collections.ArrayList;` to your use statements and then `var Al = new ArrList()`

Comment: ... and please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: What error do you get when you use `System.Collections.ArrayList`?  I would assume that would not complain about it being a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace is "ArrayList", which is the problem. This can be solved by either changing the namespace or changing

```
ArrayList A1 = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
System.Collections.ArrayList A1 = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```

However using ArrayList is not recommended, it is very old. Instead it is recommended to use List.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1)